# Error Installing Spring IDE Roo Support on Oxygen

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-roo, spring-tool-suite

I am taking a course on Sprint Boot that uses Eclipse Oxygen 14.0 so I downloaded that version (also tried latest Oxygen & got similar error). Error is as follows;

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.13.0.v20170612-0950 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.13.0.v20170612-0950)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Java Code Manipulation Functionality 1.9.0.v20161219-2145 (org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation 1.9.0.v20161219-2145)
    Java Code Manipulation Functionality 1.5.0.v20130605-1748 (org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation 1.5.0.v20130605-1748)
    Java Code Manipulation Functionality 1.9.50.v20170920-1015 (org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation 1.9.50.v20170920-1015)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AspectJ Development Tools 2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600 (org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600)
    To: org.eclipse.ajdt.ui [2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AspectJ Development Tools UI 2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600 (org.eclipse.ajdt.ui 2.2.4.e44x-20150610-1600)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation [1.3.0,1.7.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.13.0.v20170612-0950 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.13.0.v20170612-0950)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation [1.9.0.v20161219-2145]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.7.3.201602250914-RELEASE)
    To: org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.0.1
```

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ do you have the update site `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/47_aj9/dev/update`?

Comment: Thank you. Is that link also good for Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)? 

I had reverted by to Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) when I saw your replay but added the link per your instructions & was able to complete the Spring IDE Roo installation and the subsequent Sprint Tools. 


The triumph was short-lived since when I tried to create new new Spring Boot Starter project I got another error     An internal error occurred during: "Building UI model".
org/springsource/ide/eclipse/commons/core/util/StringUtil

Comment: Just a quick question: why do you want to install the Spring IDE Roo extension if you start to implement Spring Boot applications? There is no immediate need for Spring Roo from what I know. I would recommend to install the Spring Tools into an existing Eclipse Oxygen.2 install using the Eclipse Marketplace entry, that installs everything you need to get started with Spring Boot.

Comment: or you could download the ready-to-use distribution of the Spring Tool Suite, which is the latest Eclipse Oxygen.2 plus all the Spring Tools pre-installed, available from here: https://spring.io/tools

Comment: Thanks @MartinLippert for helping this n00b. Your answer
"I would recommend to install the Spring Tools into an existing Eclipse Oxygen.2 install using the Eclipse Marketplace entry, that installs everything you need to get started with Spring Boot." enabled me to continue in this course. 

I have a new problem now but will start a new question if I can't get it sorted.